# Show what has been revised in a direct revision

Tags: feature-request, edits, revisions-list

I wanted to show someone in chat a revision that someone did so I linked it to them: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17528749/3

But that just shows this:

> [image]

Which has no data about the revision.

In order to see what has been revised one has to click on Return to Revisions, then go to revision 3 and *then* and **only** then do they see what was revised: 
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17528749/revisions

> [image]

Can we please have some way to see what has been revised when going to a direct link of a revision?

Comment: @animuson -- I did not know whether bug or feature-request

Comment: @random this is not true at all `This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.`

Comment: Explain how this feature request to show the diff when linking to the exact revision is different to the other request to show the diff when linking direct to the revision

Comment: @random My question actually has some sort of reasonable solution also the other one was asking for a different thing. Mine is asking for a page update to the current linked revision. The other is asking for a direct link to the revision on the revision list. Not the same :-)

Comment: Understood. So the request is the same

Comment: Haha no not really @random Also in this post someone gives a viable solution to my question, whereas over there it is all theory.

Answer (score 5):

I think both are useful. You don't always want to see the changes, sometimes linking to the revision itself as-is is intended. So I disagree this is a bug.

As a feature request, I would love to see an option to show and hide the diff:

> [image: diff button]

Comment: Yea a UI like that would definitely be useful :-)